# mongoose update document not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to mongoose,I wasing trying to find a document by ref id and update corresponding document, but it throws an error saying "course.save is not function". Can anyone help me about this? Thanks!

[Here is the schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNYEM.png)

[Here is the api for update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoF3V.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please put the schema and code in the question as code-formatted text instead of an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your update function, you can't use it like that. The proper way to do the update would be:

```
    TrainingModel.update({ "referenceNumber": req.params.referenceNumber}, req.body(or req.params), function(err, page){
    if(err) throw err;
    res.json();
});
```

[Reference to mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer, it's working perfect now!

Comment: So can you please mark my answer as the correct one. You can do it by pressing check mark on the left of it. Thank you.